# Image upload from android app

Tags: android, image, image-uploading

In my application I'm uploading an image on to the server. Here in the below code I'm uploading an image from the drawable folder. 
But how can I upload an image from an imageview from the layout xml?
similarly like *findviewbyid.imgid*

My layout name is *main.xml* and image id is *imgid*

kindly help me...

```
 Bitmap bitmap =
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avatar);       
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
 byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
 String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can upload image using Base64 string and multipart entity

for base64 string

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        btMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); // bm is the
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        base64String = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
```

and for multipart

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/upload.php");
File file = new File(yourimagepath);

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: thanx krutik. but I wanna know that how can I fetch the image in an image view...?